# Trouble indexing a copied array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

When I use the original arrays, this works, but I want to select from a number of arrays before executing this code.

Here is a code snippet that outlines the problem. There seems to be an issue using `Index` to access a copied array. It doesn't help if I declare the copied arrays or not. Thanks for the help, I really am stuck.

```
  Set Karray = ThisWorkbook.Names("Karray").RefersToRange  ' From Workbook Defined Names
  Set Kamt = ThisWorkbook.Names("Kamt").RefersToRange      ' From Workbook Defined Names
  Dim Index as Long: Index = 0
  First_ary = Karray: Second_ary = Kamt  ' Copy arrays
  For Each element In First_ary          ' "First_ary" is useful here. 
    Index = Index + 1            ' Index keeps the two arrays being used in element number sync.
' The next line is what I want, but get "#VALUE!". Some issue using "Index" in these arrays:
    If (Second_ary(Index) Like "") Then Exit For  ' Exit on the first empty line of the array.
 .... more code ...
  Next element
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73428507/318107

Comment: Your assignments to datafield arrays result in 1-based 2-dimensional arrays, so `Second_ary(Index)` misses here a "column" argument. @SteveNeedsSheetNames

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` property of a `Range` object is always still a 2-dimensional array, even for a single row or column... it will just be a 2-dimensional array where one of the dimensions is only `1 To 1`.

Change `Second_ary(Index)` to

- `Second_ary(Index, 1)` if `Kamt` refers to a column, or
- `Second_ary(1, Index)` if `Kamt` refers to a row.